# Exclude BUILD files from rsync

Tags: shell, command-line, sh

I am trying to upload files from my local computer to a server via ssh for deployment. In the upload, I want to exclude some files like .pyc and BUILD.

I have managed to exclude all the files, but the ones called BUILD.

This is currently my (dry-run) terminal command:

```
rsync -e ssh --dry-run \
  --recursive --archive --verbose \
  --delete \
  --exclude='*.pyc' \
  --exclude='*.scss' \
  --exclude='__*.js' \
  --exclude='*BUILD' \
  --exclude='*.jar' \
  --exclude='*.DS_Store' \
  --exclude='__pycache__' \
  local_folder/ \
  server:server_folder/
```

All the exclusions work, except BUILD.

I tried:

```
--exclude='*/BUILD'
--exclude='*BUILD'
--exclude='BUILD'
```

None of the previous seems to have detected and deleted the existing BUILD files.

Any ideas on how I can exclude these files?

Thank you!

Comment: give a try without the `=`, check these examples http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/?utm_source=feedburner

Comment: It works with equal for all the others and it seems accepted: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/rsync.htm

Comment: maybe you already have the file BUILD in your remote system that's why is there, try to delete it remotely and then sync again, should be working.

Comment: I think that might be the solution. The filter seemed to be working on a fresh upload. It seems --delete does not delete excluded files.  --delete-excluded is needed for that. Want to take the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command seems to be working but could be that the `BUILD` files already existed previously.

If you have excluded files or directories from being transferred, `--delete-excluded` will remove them from the destination side, so this should work:

```
rsync -e ssh --dry-run \
--recursive --archive --verbose \
--exclude='*.pyc' \
--exclude='*.scss' \
--exclude='__*.js' \
--exclude='*BUILD' \
--exclude='*.jar' \
--exclude='*.DS_Store' \
--exclude='__pycache__' \
--delete-excluded \
local_folder/ \
server:server_folder/
```

To complement check also this answer which explain the delete options in rsync https://superuser.com/a/156702/284722